# Why does this program using fork() and wait() output 201 when I run it?

Tags: c, fork, wait

When I diagrammed this, I wrote that the possible outputs could be 3020140, 1203040, 2013040, 1302040, or 3012040. When I ran it, the output was 201. What's going on? How could the program never reach 3, and what's happening with the wait condition? I thought wait meant that that calling process would not continue until children processes had finished, meaning that it would always be at the end of output.

```
int main() {
    if (fork() != 0) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("3"); 
        }
        else {
            pid_t pid ;
            int status ;
            if ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0) {
                printf("4");            
            } 
        }
    }
    else {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("1");
            exit (0); 
        }
        printf("2"); 
    }
    printf("0");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: What system are you running this on?   201 without 3040 should be impossible - unless you are running this under some other parent that is catching signals and doing weird things.

Comment: nope, no other parents. I'm running it on a 32-bit Ubuntu virtual machine. thanks for the reply.

Comment: to start I'd add flushes after each printf, `fflush(stdout);` to see if it's related to the problem.

Comment: It runs fine on my machine, first try fflush() then try using non gui terminal (ie. ctl+alt+f2), if those do not work maybe it is because it is VM.

Answer (score 1):

One observation: the complete lack of newlines in the print statements means that the output is only flushed when the processes terminate.  This makes it harder to see what's going on.  Because the characters will be flushed when the process exits, one non-zero digit and its following zero will normally appear together.

Superficially, the 30 should appear before the 40.  However, the child that dies first could be the one that controls the printing of 1 and 20, in which case, the 40 could appear before the 30 is printed.  Note that the `wait()` function only waits for one child to die before returning, unlike the shell command `wait` with no arguments which waits for all children to die.

There's no guarantee about the relative sequencing of 1 (which won't be followed by a 0) and 20, and no guarantee about the sequencing of 30, 40 compared with 1 and 20.  The code can fail to print 3 if the fork before it fails.

When I ran the unmodified code a few times (I called the program `f7`), I got the output:

```
$ ./f7;echo
2040
301$ ./f7;echo
3020140
$ ./f7;echo
203040
1$ ./f7;echo
2030140
$ ./f7;echo
2013040
$
```

This demonstrates that the sequencing is rather arbitrary.  Sometimes, the echo completed before some of the children did.

Note that the first run shows 40 appearing before 30 or 1; I didn't even have to be selective about which runs I showed.  The machine happens to be a 12 logical core Intel-based machine running an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative, so there are plenty of cores available for child processes to use.

The first thing I'd do is add lots of diagnostic printing (with newlines) identifying what is happening where.  That means each output would include the PID.  The various parent processes would identify the PID of their children; the `wait` would report on the PID which was reported as dead. The instrumentation is written to standard error with a newline at the end of each printing operation.  The output is also echoed to standard output as originally.  I saved this code in `f11.c` and therefore ran it as `./f11`:

```
#include "posixver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void print(const char *number)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d:%s]\n", (int)getpid(), number);
    printf("%s", number);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d:initial]\n", (int)getpid());
    if ((pid = fork()) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%d:parent-1;child=%d]\n",
                (int)getpid(), (int)pid);
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            print("3");
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "[%d:parent-2;child=%d]\n",
                    (int)getpid(), (int)pid);
            int status;
            if ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "[%d:corpse=%d;status=0x%.4X]\n",
                        (int)getpid(), (int)pid, status);
                print("4");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%d:child]\n", (int)getpid());
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            print("1");
            exit(0);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "[%d:parent-3;child=%d]\n", (int)getpid(), (int)pid);
        print("2");
    }
    print("0");
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./f11;echo
[6781:initial]
[6781:parent-1;child=6782]
[6782:child]
[6781:parent-2;child=6783]
[6782:parent-3;child=6784]
[6782:2]
[6782:0]
[6784:1]
201[6783:3]
[6781:corpse=6782;status=0x0000]
[6781:4]
[6783:0]
[6781:0]
4030
$
```

Without the standard error, the output sequence would have been 2014030.

Note that I always saw the complete output (a `20`, a `30`, a `40`, and a `1`).  If you missed some output, it might be because your `PS1` prompt overwrote it (which would require an unusual but not impossible value for PS1 that included a carriage return).